# Extract Timestamp from Lightning .sqllight

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

sry for my english.
I will extract a correct timestamp from the Thunderbird Lightning Addon SQLLight File.

My SQL Statements are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cal_events (
    cal_id varchar(1000),
    id varchar(1000),
    time_created INTEGER,
    last_modified INTEGER,
    title varchar(1000),
    priority INTEGER,
    privacy varchar(1000),
    ical_status varchar(1000),
    flags INTEGER,
    event_start INTEGER,
    event_end INTEGER,
    event_stamp INTEGER,
    event_start_tz varchar(1000),
    event_end_tz varchar(1000),
    recurrence_id INTEGER,
    recurrence_id_tz varchar(1000),
    alarm_last_ack INTEGER, offline_journal INTEGER);

INSERT INTO cal_events VALUES('03278cd9-7f6a-40ab-8629-c1c3c28b97ec','59b57163-9614-47d2-8fdf-e84e784a4cd5',1316710084000000,1316710121000000,'Event Test 1',NULL,NULL,NULL,4,1317133800000000,1317135600000000,1316710121000000,'Europe/Berlin','Europe/Berlin',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

I will extract `event_start` and `event_end` to the correct Time.
But this is not a PHP Unix Timestamp.

Does somebody has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through the [Lightning source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/calendar) shows the timestamps to be stored in microseconds. To convert from microseconds to seconds (i.e. a Unix timestamp) you need to divide by 1 million:

```
select datetime(event_start/1000000, 'unixepoch') from cal_events
```

An explanation of the `unixepoch` modifier from [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> This modifier causes the DDDDDDDDDD to be interpreted not as a Julian day number as it normally would be, but as Unix Time - the number of seconds since 1970.

The SQLite `datetime` function returns in the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, e.g. `2016-10-16 16:43:01`. Don't forget to check the timezone field too!

Comment: @timcluttonVery nic

Comment: Very nice. Thanks.